# PL/SQL Function homework

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql

Is it possible to join a query in PL/SQL function? My function does not compile properly when using a join. Is there another method to solve this problem?

## Problem

Create a PL/SQL function for each of the three rules. The function accepts one parameter, the AppID, and returns 0 – Not Acceptable, or 1 - Acceptable

## Tables

APPLICANTS (SSN, FirstName, LastName, DOB)
ACADEMIES (AcadID, AcadName)
APPLICATIONS (AppID, SSN, AcadID, Year)
MEDICAL_RECORDS (SSN, Pulse, Systolic, Diastolic, DateUpdated)
EVAL_RULES (RuleID, FunctionName)
EVALUATIONS (EvalID, EvalDate, AppID)
RESULTS (EvalID, RuleID, Result)

## Function Rules

Age:

1. 16 <= age <=22 and (USAFA or USMA) – “Acceptable”
2. 16 <= age <= 40 and USUHS – “Acceptable”
3. Otherwise – “Not Acceptable”

Pulse:

1. Pulse < 45 – “Not Acceptable”
2. 45 <= Pulse <= 99 – “Acceptable”
3. Pulse > 99 -  “Not acceptable”

Blood Pressure:

1. Systolic < 140 and Diastolic < 90 – “Acceptable”
2. Systolic >= 140 or Diastolic >= 90 – “Unacceptable”

Comment: You can use joins in a query that is inside a function

Comment: Would you post what you've done so far so we can see why it isn't compiling?

Comment: What does "join a query" mean? You can use any query you want.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an implementation of the first set of rules, for AGE. It is untested.

```
create or replace function validate_age
   ( p_app_id in applications.appid%type)
   return varchar2
is
    cursor appcur (p_id applications.appid%type) is
        select apt.dob
               , aca.acadname
        from applications app
             join applicants apt on app.ssn = apt.ssn
             join academies aca on app.acadid = aca.acadid;
    apprec appcur%rowtype;    
    return_value varchar2(20);
    age number;
begin
    open appcur(p_app_id);
    fetch appcur into apprec;
    -- basic error handling
    if appcur%notfound then
        raise_application_error(-20000, 'Invalid Application number ['|| p_app_id ||']');
    end if;
    -- age = whole number of years between now and date of birth
    age := trunc(months_between(sysdate, apprec.dob)/12);

    if (age between 16 and 22 and apprec.acadname in ('USAFA', 'USMA'))
    then 
        return_value:= 'Acceptable';
    elsif (age between 16 and 40 and apprec.acadname in ('USUHS'))
    then 
        return_value:= 'Acceptable';
    else
        return_value:= 'Not Acceptable”';
    end if;

    close appcur;
    return return_value;
end validate_age;
/
```

Extending this template to handle the other rules should be a piece of cake.

Remember to acknowledge StackOverflow when you hand in your homework!